# Structure of multilingual and multiregional directory listing website for translation

Tags: multisite, translation, directory, multi-language, plugin-wpml

What is the best translation structure for a multilingual and multiregional directory website? Let's say our listing owners as members of our work team are from  around 20 different countries with different languages and I want each of them to submit their listings in the official language of their country and all the listings are aggregated on our site which has the default English language. Our directory site, whose default language is English, will be translated into at least twenty other languages. In this case, we want the listings to be usable both locally for the country of listing owners and for other countries globally. Do I need to use WordPress MULTISITE? Should I use multiple separate sites that link to each other or can I use a special plugin like WPML?

Comment: That sounds very complex, however I'm not sure what you're after. Please add more details and description as to what you want to achive. Maybe an image, diagram or something. What to you mean by "directory website"?

Comment: @user3135691 Thank you for your comment. Suppose our team consists of a group of vendors who submit physical products as well as bookable products to our marketplace and directory listing website. The listing owners who are in different countries  submit their listings only in the official language of their country. In other words, sellers in France submit their listings in French and sellers in Egypt submit their listings only in Arabic, and in the case of sellers in Spain, in Spanish, etc.

Comment: @user3135691 Our website, which is a marketplace and directory listing website as well as multilingual, offers its products in the default English language as well as in several other languages that are translated.
In this case:
The most important thing we need is for the content of the website (products and submissions sent from different countries in different languages) to be translated into English and displayed on our site in English.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From what I can assume with the additional information, it is not neccessary to build this as a multisite. WPML can do this all in one System. Create a website with WordPress, enable WPML and translate all posts/pages with the Advanced Translation Editor. You should then be able to create an upload page in the required languages (translated by WPML) etc. However, from what you are describing this is going to be a longer process of evaluating and translating all the strings on the frontend as well as managing all the data in the backend.

Comment: @user3135691 Thank you so much for your consideration and good solution!